# C# VS2012 build application in not working with Win7 machine

Tags: c#

I have created one C# form base application in VS2012 and Windows 8. This application is working fine in Win 8 machine but facing 2 problems in Windows 7

1. I have used one statusStrip in that application with layout style HorizontalStackWithOverflow. This status Strip lable's text is properly seen in Windows 8 machine  but with windows 7 machine it shows text in mirror image text format.
2. Some forms are not getting opened in Win 7 machine.

Please help me on this

Comment: More detail needed.  Windows Forms / WPF? How do you make the thing appear in your controls? ...

Comment: I have used Win forms and and status strip control is dragged on form by toolbar.

Comment: Show code, and edit the question :)

Comment: Form is not opening in windows 7:  
main form is calling EditParameter   form for that I have crated its object and by that object calling its one method as below

   frm_EditParameter obj_EditParameter = new frm_EditParameter();
        if (obj_EditParameter.GetParamData(Param_Info, rowIndex) != true)

At the end of GetParamData param I have used
this.show() // to open a form

Comment: This above code is working with win8 but not on win7.

Comment: By using Visual Studio 2012, you are testing your app on .NET 4.5 on Windows 8. Unless you installed .NET 4.5 on Windows 7, I am not surprised to see any issue.

Comment: with win7 4.5 .Net framework same issue persist. Please help on this

Comment: Thanks for help. I have used line control on those forms and it have  Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=10.0.0.0,    Culture=neutral dependency.